# How to make Jenkins work with watir-webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, jenkins, opera, watir-webdriver, jenkins-plugins

I am running a jenkins installation in the cloud and am using Linux Ubuntu Precise Pangolin 64 bit.

I have configured everything properly for ubuntu using the instructions found here (with some modifications):

https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/blob/master/installation/ubuntu.md

Now everything works fine when I go into irb and run

```
require "watir-webdriver"
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto "google.com"
b.text
b.close
```

It works well magically for opera also if i replace :chrome with :opera in the above code.

However, when running my test scripts through Jenkins, I get a multitude of timeout errors and such.

Only firefox seems to be working from within jenkins. Both "google-chrome" and "opera" programs are located in /usr/bin

I installed both the xvfb and xvnc plugins for jenkins.

I am able to login through vnc and see the tests being run for firefox only. I will very very very greatly appreciate it if someone shows me how to make both chrome and opera also work from within jenkins by using watir-webdriver.

I have read blog posts about this here:

http://nepalonrails.tumblr.com/post/14217655627/set-up-jenkins-ci-on-ubuntu-for-painless-rails3-app-ci

http://www.geisterstunde.org/wordpress/?p=239

http://watirmelon.com/2011/08/29/running-your-watir-webdriver-tests-in-the-cloud-for-free/

I found these resources very helpful but now I am stuck. I would greatly appreciate any help or pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide error messages. You did not say what you mean by "in the cloud". Amazon EC2? I had similar problems when I was using the smallest Amazon EC2 instance, since does not have a lot of RAM, and probably Jenkins takes the most of it.

Comment: Actually I'm on rackspace with about 14GB of ram. I will provide you the error messages once my current build starts failing again. Thank you for the quick response! I heard you on a podcast about saucelabs and watir!